# Single word per line in kivy(GridLayout)

Tags: scrollview, kivy

I'm trying to make a app similar a menu. I already did scrollview with gridLayout, but I don't know how to show this separate, for instance, in the left column names, and in the right column age, in this way the app may have variable number of rows (infinity). I hope I have been less confusing as possible, the same for my english. Thanks everybody, I didn't post my code here because I think it isn't necessary. Bye, have a good day.

Comment: You *definetly* should show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ass is important I post my code here, I'm going to try to post. I'm sorry for the mistakes like indent. 

.py
    class PrimeiroScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = 'home'
        super(Screen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
class SegundoScreen(Screen):
    text = StringProperty('')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = 'dois'
        super(Screen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
class RootScreen(ScreenManager):
    pass
class scrollmanageApp(App):
   def build(self):
        return RootScreen()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    appVar = scrollmanageApp()
    scrollmanageApp().run()
```

.kv

```
<RootScreen>:
    PrimeiroScreen:
    SegundoScreen:

<PrimeiroScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: (.3,.15)
        pos_hint:{'x': .35, 'y': .84}
        Label:
            text: "Teste de união scrollview com screenmanage"
            font_size: '30dp'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        rows: 2
        size_hint: (.20,.10)
        pos_hint:{'x': .25, 'y': .64}       
        Button:
            text: "Scrollview!"
            font_size: '30dp'
            text_size: self.size
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'dois'

<SegundoScreen>:
    text: 'This is just a test ' * 50
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: 1, 1
        pos_hint:{'x': .0, 'y': .0}
        size: 100, 100
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            #rows: 
            padding: 10
            spacing: 10
            size_hint: None, None
            width: 500
            height: self.minimum_height
            Label:
                text: root.text
                font_size: 50
                text_size: self.width, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]

    Button:
        text: "Voltar!"
        size_hint: .1, .1
        pos_hint:{'x': .9, 'y': .0}
        text_size: self.width, None
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'home'
```

I hope I had sucess in this time(post my code).Very thanks!